# Verb (+adv./prep.)

Tags: grammar, verbs

There are innumerable verbs that should be followed by "adverbs or preposition", but at the same time, they are **not** "phrasal verbs"

My question is: why we put the adverbs and preposition after the verbs, does it to complete the meaning or these specific kind of verbs cannot stand alone "without prep or adv"

Look at this example:

> - several students were ***slouching*** ***against*** the wall.

In the dictionary mentioned that we the verb "slouch" should be followed either a prep or an adv.

Does that mean we cannot put the sentence in this form:- several students were slouching.?

**I really have this problem that I can't *determine* whether some verbs needs "prep or adv" or not.**

Look at these following examples. 
-the ponies ***galloped*** ***along*** the sand or galloped off.

Why can't we take "along..." or "off" and stay the sentence makes sense.

- the man ***lurched*** drunkenly ***out*** of the bar.
- They ***rode*** ***along*** narrow country lanes.

Comment: Locatives express a relationship of the action to the physical world. Those relationships are quite varied in terms of their motion, direction, force, duration, etc.  Verbs like **lurch** refer to a type of motion in the abstract, but that motion can be situated in the physical world with a locative prepositional phrase.  There is no phrasal verb **lurch out**. The only ways to know whether a particular verb is phrasal is to engage in conversation over time with native speakers, to read, to watch movies and TV, and to study lists in grammar textbooks.

Comment: The verb itself contains no morphological clues in that regard.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. U mean that such as these verbs are imaginable or only existed in ideal world, unless we provide them with a prep/adv. but i didn't understand your second comment "the verb itself contains no morphological clues in that regard. I want ur recommendations of textbooks that cover my question further more. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Second comment: there's no way to know, just from looking at the verb infinitive form, whether it *requires* a preposition for its intended meaning. First comment: *He lurched* is grammatical, but it is very vague and disconnected from the real world. It simply refers to a *lurching motion* in the abstract. But if we say *He lurched **against the door*** we have the additional information that he made contact with the door.  The prepositional phrases add concrete detail to the action.

Comment: If we come to know that a verb is intransitive (as **lurch** is) we will then know that we cannot say "He lurched the bar".  Intransitive verbs are connected to their complements with prepositions. But again, there's no way to know that a verb is intransitive or transitive just by looking at its infinitive form. And many verbs can act in either manner.

Comment: U r totally right. But a person as a native speaker if he knows the meaning of the verb, he would recognize the verb whether it requires a prep or adv or not. Because it sounds clumsy or weird by a native listener when he put it wrong. Please, if u have recommended books, give me their names.  @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Look at this example. I came down from the burning mount. So if u take the preposition "down" out of the sentence. Would the meaning change from physical motion to abstract motion? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Yes it does make a difference.  Without **down**, he could have come here from the burning mount, by bus, on the highway. The mount could be 100 miles away. We wouldn't know that he *descended*. All we know is that the distance between here and the burning mount was traversed, in the abstract.  We don't know if here is some distance away from the mount or at the base of the mount.

Comment: And without **from** we wouldn't know whether the mount was the starting point or the destination.  I have come to the mount.  I have come from the mount.

Comment: There is no shortage of books. Google "best book on phrasal verbs" if you're interested in phrasal verbs. or "best book on prepositions" if the latter. Many results will appear.  I would use such books in combination with graded readers.

Comment: You said that i should read "phrasal verbs books" but these kind of verbs are **not** phrasal verbs. See this link of the verb "come down" this verb can either be a phrasal verb " see this link http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-down?q=Come+down+ or can be be followed by a prep and stay a normal verb as in this link http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come_1?q=Come+  @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: I said **Google "best book on phrasal verbs" if you're interested in phrasal verbs. or "best book on prepositions" if the latter.**

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it. @Tᴚoɯɐuo